# Java Framework IDE

Tags: java, terminology

Hi anybody please tell me the difference between IDE and a FRAMEWORK ,suppose that am using eclipse (for java) by default which framework am following.

Comment: the answer was good , now i get an idea about this two,in earlier i think both are same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDE Stands for Integrated Development Environment and is a tool that allows you to program in a certain language and usually includes an integrated compiler, debugger, syntax highlighting and various other tools that allow you to develop applications quicker. E.g. Eclipse IDE, Visual Studio, Netbeans IDE.

A framework is a library or set of classes that makes it easier to implement a certain type of application and is usually deployed with your application. It usually provides a structure that you need to adhere to and various helper classes. E.g. Spring Framework, .Net MVC, Struts etc.

Comment: Yes, but to complexify things Eclipse and Netbeans are also frameworks. See, for example, http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform.

Answer (score 1):

IDE is the development environment, the editor where you would normally write code. It also might include a compiler, debugger, ... A framework is a set of reusable libraries or classes which you could use in your code.

Comment: Integrated = the editor + compiler + debugger + documentation browser and other niceties.

Answer (score 0):

Some IDE's (eclipse, netbeans) offer a *framework* (eclipse RCP, netbeans RCP) that allows for developing (Java) applications based on (parts of) the IDE's code and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

An IDE is a graphical desktop application (e.g. Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ, etc.) that helps you create, run, test, debug, and manage (e.g. version control) your source files (production/test code, resources, and documentation).

A framework is third-party code that determines the structure of some part (maybe all) of your own source code. You work *within* a framework, i.e. you follow its rules, enjoy its benefits, and suffer its limitations (although a good framework offers extension points to minimise these).  Contrast this with a library, which is a collection of code units (e.g. functions, classes, etc.) from which you draw as necessary, but without constraining the structure of your own code. Using a framework is a bigger architectural decision than using a library. A typical enterprise project will use one or more frameworks and several libraries.